# Are C++ #ifndef preprocessor statements slow?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I've heard some things online, both positive and negative, about preprocessor statements, and I was just curious as to how fast these are.

Say you include the same library (which has `#ifndef` guards) 5 times, will it take any significantly longer period of time to run, or is it so miniscule it has no real effect?

I might have missed one, but didn't find any answer to this elsewhere.

Comment: They're preprocessor statements. They don't "run" at all in the final program. They get replaced during preprocessing phase

Comment: As mentioned above they are not relevant for run-time. Maybe you are referring to compilation time (which I would also not worry about) ?

Comment: The first thing you need to know is that C++ is usually a *compiled* language. The compiler consumes source code and outputs an executable file. The executable file then can run as many times as you need. Redundant preprocessor directives may affect compilation speed, but they don't change the bytes of the executable, so also not its speed.

Comment: `#ifndef guards` are not for speed of any kind. They are just to ensure that symbols are defined only once when header is included. Anyway this is one of things inherited form C which maybe C++ soon will get rid of, by using modules.

Comment: It would have no effect on the speed of the program running (if the code does compile). It could effect the speed of the compiling and without the include guards your program may not compile at all.

Comment: You could check what effect the number of `#ifndef`s has on the assember output: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/4a3fbPYK5) - add and remove them as you please to see the effect

Comment: I recommend experimenting to see how much longer they take.  I know for my project, use of them can greatly improve build time, and misuse of them can greatly adversely impact build time.  But my project has over 50 million lines of code, and may not have the same build profile that your project has.

Comment: If you are concerned about the performance of including the same header over and over, then check if your compiler offers any kind of *precompiled headers* feature.

Comment: "significantly longer" **than what**? If you don't use them you'll end up spending lots of time dealing with mysterious error messages.

Comment: Just what do you think "run" means in this case?  No, please, define "run".

Comment: Each time an `#ifndef` is parsed (and the preprocessor skips over text until the corresponding `#endif`) there may be some minor (barely measurable) impact.  Most compilers (preprocessors) are optimised to handle repeated inclusion of headers, so mitigate any impact.   On balance, other things have a huge (several orders of magnitude larger) impact on build time than use of `#ifndef`/`#endif` include guards. Such as using a "globals.h" that is `#include`d everywhere and itself `#include`s lots of other headers (so every source file in the project is recompiled if any header changes)

Comment: I did mean "compile" and not "run", sorry about the bad wording, and thank you for all the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compilers have been smart about header include guards for many years.  They know that including the same header many times is very common, and they have optimizations to deal with it.

So, don't worry about this.  If you want to speed up your build, first find out what part of it is slow.

Comment: thank you! I don't have any specific problems with this at the moment, I was just curious as to whether or not this is something I should be careful of in the future, and this answers that!